# How to determine End Of Life for Eclipse versions

Tags: eclipse

How do I determine the end of life date for Eclipse versions?

I have googled for Eclipse end of life and found this discussion:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/160291/

But there was nothing in the conversation about the actual dates for EOL.

Comment: Usually for each Eclipse version, there is the original and 2 updates.  Once the second update is released, there's no more development for that Eclipse version.  Use whichever version of Eclipse you want.  You're not required to upgrade unless something external happens, like moving from Java 7 to Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse doesn't really seem to use the term 'End of Life' at all. The [Eclipse Project Archive](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) site contains every release of Eclipse back to version 1.0 in 2001.

However only the current release is actively maintained with bug fixes and then only until the second fix release. Since Eclipse 3.0 the main product release has been annually in June followed by a fix release in September and another in the following February. So at the time of writing (March 2016) the second fix release of Eclipse 4.5 Mars (4.5.2) was released recently.

Bugs reported after the second fix release are included in the next major release (currently Eclipse 4.6 Neon).